# Search number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, numbers

I've got a string with numbers and text, and I need to find in that string a number that always starts with "9" and has a length of 8 numbers. How should I do it?

For example:

```
"customer 92345678 and customer 9234"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/9\d{1,8}/` should do what you want.

Comment: You can use a regular expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @George should be `/9\d{8}/`

Comment: @GottZ I was assuming it could be _up to_ 8 numbers based on the second example `customer 9234`

Comment: lets just say this question is unclear then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
function f ()
 {

var text = 'customer 92345678 and customer 9234';
var regex = /9\d{7}/g;

var match = regex.exec(text);

return(match[0]);

 }
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

please find below exemple with regular expression

```
var re = /9\d{7}/g;
var str = 'customer 92345678 and customer 9234';
var myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfecly with console.log, but unfortunately I am working on a program that´t doesn´t support it and I need to use return.Unfortunately when I use return here it doesn´t work, any Idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [Regular Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

I am assuming you have a really long string:

```
var str = 'customer92345678 customer12345678 customer1234 customer9234 customer98765432';
```

According to your question, there should only be two valid strings that you are trying to search from the example above.

**String solution - [String.prototype.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)**

```
var searched = str.match(/\w{1,}9\d{7}/g);

console.log(searched); // outputs ['customer92345678', 'customer98765432']
```

However, if you have an array of strings (which is more logical):

```
var arr = ['customer92345678', 'customer12345678', 'customer1234', 'customer9234', 'customer98765432'];
```

**Array solution 1 - [Array.prototype.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)**

```
var searched = arr.filter(function(value){
    return /9\d{7}/.test(value);
});

console.log(searched);  // outputs ['customer92345678', 'customer98765432']
```

**Array solution 2 - [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)**

```
var searched = [];

arr.forEach(function(value){
    if (!/9\d{7}/.test(value)) return;
    searched.push(value);
});

console.log(searched); // outputs ['customer92345678', 'customer98765432']
```

**Array solution 3 - [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)**

```
var searched = [],
    len = arr.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (!/9\d{7}/.test(arr[i])) continue;
    searched.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(searched); // outputs ['customer92345678', 'customer98765432']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not using Arrays because it is an external text file. I assume that the String solution should work fine, but unfotunately my program does not recognize console.log, it says that "console" it is not defined. It is possible to get the value with return?

Comment: Just create a function with the solution and return searched. Just out of curiousity, what program are you using? Is this not a web-based project?

Comment: I am using script for Automation Engine, a program from a company named ESKO.